# Bivariate and multivariate analysis

Tags: regression, logistic, multivariate-analysis, bivariate

Most of researcher when conducting binary logistic regression analysis they use to contradictory analysis

1. Bivariate analysis or bivariable analysis to select variables that fit model,then
   2.multivariate logistic regression or multivariable analysis
   Which one is correct?? Bivariate analysis and multivariable logistic regression or bivariable analysis and multivariable logistic regression analysis?

Comment: This is hard to read. Do you have an example in a cited paper online? Are you saying that authors will fit a bunch of baseline variables (X1, X2, X3) against the response (Y) to identify variables to include in the model, then finally they fit their Y against the main X adding whichever of X1, X2, or X3 was found as significant in the previous steps?

Comment: "Bivariable" means you have two predictors (a.k.a. "independent variables"). "Bivariate" means that you have two _responses_ ("dependent variables"). They are often confused. The general terms are "multivariable" vs. "multivariate". Apologies for the pedantic nitpick.